# Substracting and dividing input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, input

trying to do some math on a few input fields it is giving me some problems

here is what i am tring to do

1. subtract retail cost from discount show in customer cost
2. then subtract customer cost from down payment and divide by term to get installment
3. select menu for term if changed then recalculate installment

here is the fiddle
  http://jsfiddle.net/alienfactory1/GnTJ6/6/

```
 $( '#Discount' ).keyup(function() {
        paymentmethod();                         
    });

    $( '#finterm' ).change(function(){
            if ($('#finterm').val() == 12){
                  paymentmethod();
            } else if($('#finterm').val() == 18) {
                  paymentmethod();
            }
    });

     function paymentmethod(){

    var retailcost =  parseFloat($('#RetailCost').val().replace(/,/g, ''));
    var discount =  parseFloat($('#Discount').val());
    var downpay = parseFloat($('#DownPayment').val());
    var term = parseInt($('#finterm').val());
    var customercost =  $('#CustomerCost').val(retailcost - discount);

    var installment = customercost - downpay;
    var instald = installment / term;
    var test = $('#Instalments').val(instald); 
    $('#CustomerCost').autoNumeric('set', $(this).val());  
                     }

Retail Cost
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Retail Cost" id="RetailCost" readonly value="3,145.00"><br>
Discount
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Discount" id="Discount"><br>
Cust Cost
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Customer Cost" id="CustomerCost" readonly><br>
Down Pay
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Down Payment"   id="DownPayment" readonly><br>
Term
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="finterm">
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
</select><br>
Installments
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Installments" id="Instalments" readonly>
```

Comment: can you be more specific on "some problems"¿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that could be two problems:

1) DownPayment is never set.
2) in your code, customercost  is an object;

try this demo when i set DownPayment  to 2

http://jsfiddle.net/c6Xs5/1/

```
var retailcost =  parseFloat($('#RetailCost').val().replace(/,/g, ''));
var discount =  parseFloat($('#Discount').val());
var downpay = parseFloat($('#DownPayment').val());
var term = parseInt($('#finterm').val());
var customercost =  retailcost - discount;
$('#CustomerCost').val(customercost);                 
var installment = customercost - downpay;
var instald = installment / term;
var test = $('#Instalments').val(instald); 
$('#CustomerCost').autoNumeric('set', $(this).val());  
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `parseInt` and `parseFloat` so JavaScript can do proper math.